# MVC - Add ViewBag a Seletlist for DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

Controller:

```
string a = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        ViewBag.ylr = new SelectList(new SelectList(
                    Enumerable.Range(2020, 50)
                        .Select(r => new
                        {
                            Text = new DateTime(r, 1, 1).ToString("yyyy"),
                            Value = r.ToString()
                        }),
                    "Value", "Text", "").ToString(),
        a);
```

resurt:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EAYb.jpg)

I wanna return years "text" and "Value", How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why anyone doesn't help me~
Actually I found solution alone, even so I'll share solution:

```
 ViewBag.ylr = new SelectList(new SelectList(
                    Enumerable.Range(2020, 50)
                        .Select(r => new
                        {
                            Text = new DateTime(r, 1, 1).ToString("yyyy"),
                            Value = r.ToString()
                        }),
                    "Value", "Text", "").ToList(),"Value","Text", a.ToString());
```